# C++ How can I keep the turret rotating on the same axis as the tank? (2D tank commander game)

Tags: c++, trigonometry

So this is the code from the section of the program that I am having trouble with. My goal is to get the turret to rotate, but I need it to rotate it on the axis of the tank so that its movement looks kinda natural. I have no idea what to do, everything I've tried doesn't work, so I just need to know where to go from here. and the computeGradient function was given, so I have to use that in figuring out how to change the turret's x and y position. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "engine.h"
#include "constants.h"

using namespace std;

void initTankState(float& tankX, float& tankY, float& turretX, float& turretY, int& tankAngle, int& turretAngle){
    tankX = SCREEN_WIDTH/2;
    tankY = SCREEN_HEIGHT*.75;
    turretX = tankX;
    turretY = tankY;
    tankAngle = 0;
    turretAngle = 0;
}


void loadInfantryData(string path, int& numInfantry, float*& infantryPosX, float*& infantryPosY, int*& infantryAngle){
    fstream fin;
    fin.open(path, ios::in);

    fin>>numInfantry;

    for (int i = 0; i<numInfantry; i++)
    {
        fin>>infantryPosX[i]>>infantryPosY[i]>>infantryAngle[i];
    }

}

void changeGameState(string command, float& tankX, float& tankY, float& turretX, float& turretY, int & tankAngle, int & turretAngle, int numInfantry, float* infantryPosX, float* infantryPosY, int* infantryAngle){

    float x;
    float y;

    computeGradient(x, y, tankAngle);

    /*if (command == "up")
        moveForward(tankX, tankY, tankAngle);
    else if (command =="down")
        moveBackward(tankX, tankY, tankAngle);
    else*/ if (command == "left")
        turnLeft(tankX, tankY, tankAngle);
    else if (command == "right")
        turnRight(tankX, tankY, tankAngle);
    else if (command == "pleft")
    {
        panLeft(turretAngle);
        turretX = x;
        turretY = y;
    }
    else if (command == "pright")
    {
        panRight(turretAngle);
        turretX = x;
        turretY = y;
    }

}

void updateTurret(float, float, float&, float&, int, int)
{
}
void panLeft(int &turretAngle) //here
{
    turretAngle++;
    if (turretAngle <0)
        turretAngle = TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1;
    if (turretAngle >TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1)
        turretAngle = 0;


}
void panRight(int &turretAngle) //and here are where I've run into a block
{
    turretAngle--;
    if (turretAngle >TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1)
        turretAngle = 0;
    if (turretAngle <0)
        turretAngle = TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1;
}
void moveForward(float &, float &, int &, float)
{
}
void moveBackward(float &, float &, int &, float)
{
}
void turnLeft(float &tankX, float &tankY, int &tankAngle)
{
    tankAngle++;
    if (tankAngle <0)
        tankAngle = TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1;
    if (tankAngle >TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1)
        tankAngle = 0;
}
void turnRight(float &tankX, float &tankY, int &tankAngle)
{
    tankAngle--;
    if (tankAngle <0)
        tankAngle = TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1;
    if (tankAngle >TANK_NUM_SPRITES-1)
        tankAngle = 0;
}
void noAction(float &, float &, int &)
{
}

//Trigonometric Calculation
void computeGradient(float & dx, float & dy, int tankAngle){
    int tmpAngle = ( (TANK_NUM_SPRITES-tankAngle))%TANK_NUM_SPRITES;
    float radianAngle=(2*PI)*(float(tmpAngle)/TANK_NUM_SPRITES)-(PI/2.0);
    dx = cos(radianAngle);
    dy = sin(radianAngle);
}
```

Comment: C++ is object oriented. Using a class for Tank and Turret may be a good idea.

Comment: Even if you were writing in C, you could use a struct for your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using/trusting a function that you don't understand unless you absolutely have to. I would recommend learning the math behind computeGradients, which is readily available online. My linear algebra is kind of rusty, so I can't help too much with the trig. I think it boils down to keeping track of the position, direction, and right vectors of the tank, and the horizontal and vertical angles. The math is similar to that described [here.](http://3dgep.com/?p=1700)

From what I DO remember, you must translate the tank to the origin of world space, apply the linear transformation matrices (rotation in this case), and then translate it back to its position (I don't know if computeGradients does that implicitly). This is based off my limited knowledge of how model matrices in OpenGL works.

Anyways I hope any of what I said helped.